# In Sequelize.js is there a way to store Executing (default): log to a variable?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have already tried using JavaScript replace() method to individually do the replacements to obtain the log of the sequelize statement.

But if there is a way to do this using the sequelize library i would prefer that as i have a lot of sequelize queries and it would be time consuming and messy to use JavaScript replace() everywhere.

**Sequelize.js statement**

```
sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE column1 LIKE :column1 OR column2 LIKE :column2 OR column3 LIKE :column3 LIMIT 1000',
                        { replacements: { column1: srchterm, column2: srchterm, column3: srchterm }, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT }
                    )
```

**Log produced that I want to store to a variable**

```
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM myTable  WHERE column1 LIKE '%abc%' OR column2 LIKE '%def%' OR column3 LIKE '%hij%' LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom logging function that will be executed each time `Sequelize` would log something ([Documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor)). For example:

```
new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'pass', { logging: yourCustomLogFunction })
```

It can be set globally or per query.

Comment: Thanks! managed to get it to work per query using this   `sequelize.options.logging = str =>{log = str,console.log(str)} ;`